# Stuck trying to scroll two Listboxes from "for" loop

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I'm trying to learn how to create more advanced widget combinations in Tkinter and am having a difficult time since the documentation is scarce. Each frame gets a day and balance list box, along with a scrollbar that should scroll both list boxes per frame. Currently each scrollbar is only scrolling via middle mouse button or drag scrolling. Using the scrollbar arrows does nothing and each list box is scrolling independently. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong in my code below.

```
class BalanceLog:
    def month(self):
        month = [
            ['January', 31],
            ['February', 28],  # Check for leap year
            ['March', 31],
            ['April', 30],
            ['May', 31],
            ['June', 30],
            ['July', 31],
            ['August', 31],
            ['September', 30],
            ['October', 31],
            ['November', 30],
            ['December', 31]
        ]
        year = 2020

        mainFrame = tk.Frame(tkRoot)
        mainFrame.config(bd=2, relief='groove')
        mainFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=70)

        trxLabel = tk.Label(mainFrame, text='Transactions ' + str(year), font='courierNew 20 bold')
        trxLabel.grid(row=0, columnspan=12, pady=(20, 0))

        # Hold each month frame
        self.monthFrame = []
        self.dayList = []
        self.endBalList = []
        self.vScroll = []

        for i in range(12):
            monthLabel = tk.Label(mainFrame, text=month[i][0], font='courierNew 12 bold')
            monthLabel.grid(row=1, column=i, pady=(20, 0))

            self.monthFrame.append(tk.Frame(mainFrame))
            self.monthFrame[i].config(bd=2, relief='groove')
            self.monthFrame[i].grid(row=2, column=i, sticky=tk.W)

            dayLabel = tk.Label(self.monthFrame[i], text='Day', font='courierNew 8 bold')
            dayLabel.config(relief='raised')
            dayLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

            endBalLabel = tk.Label(self.monthFrame[i], text='Ending Balance', font='courierNew 8 bold')
            endBalLabel.config(relief='raised')
            endBalLabel.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

            self.dayList.append(tk.Listbox(self.monthFrame[i], width=3))
            self.dayList[i].config(bd=2, relief='sunken')
            self.dayList[i].grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

            self.endBalList.append(tk.Listbox(self.monthFrame[i], width=16))
            self.endBalList[i].config(bd=2, relief='raised', background='DARK GRAY')
            self.endBalList[i].grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

            self.vScroll.append(tk.Scrollbar(self.monthFrame[i], orient='vertical'))
            self.vScroll[i].grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=(tk.N, tk.S, tk.E))

            self.getFrame(idx=i)

            # Insert data
            for j in range(month[i][1]):
                self.dayList[i].insert(tk.END, 1 + j)
                self.endBalList[i].insert(tk.END, '999,999,999.99')

    def getFrame(self, idx):
        self.dayList[idx].config(yscrollcommand=self.vScroll[idx].set)
        self.endBalList[idx].config(yscrollcommand=self.vScroll[idx].set)
        self.scrollAll(idx)

    def scrollAll(self, idx):
        self.dayList[idx].yview(idx)
        self.endBalList[idx].yview(idx)
```

Comment: if tkinter is your GUI why not tag your question with it. `user-interface` doesn't tell us anything

Comment: I updated the code.

Comment: Please try to reduce this code down to a [mcve]. It looks like there is some code that isn’t necessary to reproduce a problem related to a list box. Also, you haven’t assigned a command to the scroll bar.

Comment: I can't add a command to the scrollbar if it's in a list. I'll get an error like "'list' object has no attribute 'config'".

Comment: re: _"I can't add a command to the scrollbar if it's in a list. "_ - sure you can. The fact you're using a list doesn't matter at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to assign `command` option to scrollbars.

Below are modified `getFrame()` and `scrollAll()` functions:

```
def getFrame(self, idx):
    self.dayList[idx].config(yscrollcommand=self.vScroll[idx].set)
    self.endBalList[idx].config(yscrollcommand=self.vScroll[idx].set)
    self.vScroll[idx].config(command=lambda *args: self.scrollAll(idx, *args))

def scrollAll(self, idx, *args):
    self.dayList[idx].yview(*args)
    self.endBalList[idx].yview(*args)
```

Comment: Oh you are awesome, I have been stuck on this issue for weeks, it finally works! Are there any guides or books you would recommend for more advanced Tkinter techniques? It seems like most tutorials I have viewed only cover really basic stuff like creating buttons, but none really seem to get into linking widgets.

Comment: I usually read the reference documents.  SO is also a good place to gain techniques on using tkinter as there are many experience guys with awesome and incredible ideas.

Comment: I know in my previous post you showed me how to to this same task embedding tkinter into a class. Is there a benefit to embedding vs the way I'm doing this with lists?

Comment: Using OOP is easier to design and troubleshooting.

Comment: when you scroll a listbox the other listbox does not scroll

Comment: In the previous question you already solved the scroll problem and you refactored the code to make it more usable/readable. The OP does not read the answers.